# dataType checking question in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to see if the datagrid.datasource is of a particular type then take different action.

```
if grid.datasource is CollectionBase then 
' do sone thing 
else if grid.datasource is IEnumerable then 
' do other thing
end if
```

The first check gives me CollectionBase is a type and cannot be used a expression. What does that mean?

UPDATE 1:

I checked and it seems I am sending an array of objects to the grid. Something like Customers[]. How can I make it generic so I can get the array and also somehow get the count.

Comment: My updates should answer your Update question. Although if you use `TryCast` you don't have to check for the type up front as it will return null if the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if grid.datasource.GetType() is GetType(CollectionBase) then 
    Dim myCollection as CollectionBase = TryCast(grid.DataSource, CollectionBase)
    If (myCollection IsNot Nothing) Then
        myCollection.Count
    End If
else if grid.datasource.GetType() is GetType(IEnumerable) then 
    Dim myCollection as IEnumerable= TryCast(grid.DataSource, IEnumerable)
    If (myCollection IsNot Nothing) Then
        myCollection.Count()
    End If
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TypeOf … Is …`:

```
If TypeOf grid.datasource Is CollectionBase Then
' do sone thing 
Else If TypeOf grid.datasource Is IEnumerable Then
' do other thing
End If
```

Merely using `Is` checks for identity of two objects. However, the second operand in your code *isn’t* an object, it’s a type name.